# Set visibility of a gridview element

Tags: android

I have created one gridview and use custom adapter for that. I added two images inside grid view.one is image and another one looks like close button (which is the same in all grid view items). the close button is set invisible in the beginning, i have another button in my activity, what i want is : when i click this button, i want to set the close button in every element of my grid view, but for now, when click on it, nothing happens.
below is my code :

```
    ImageView deleteFavorImage;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browser);
    .....

    GridView favorGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.favorGrid);
    favorGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    .....
    View customView = findViewById(R.id.costumButton);
    customView.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.costumButton:
        deleteFavorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
    .....
    }
```

This is my image adaptor code:

```
           @Override
       public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       {

           View MyView = convertView;
           final int pos=position;

           LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) MyContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.favor_item, null);


           ImageView iv = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.favor_item_image);
           iv.setImageResource(favorSites.get(pos));

           deleteFavorImage = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.favDelete);
           deleteFavorImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dubtndelete);

           return MyView;
       }
```

And finally this is my XML file code:

```
           <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="85dp"
android:layout_height="85dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/dufavframe" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.test.favorsites.AspectRatioImageView android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/favor_item_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView android:id="@+id/favDelete" android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-3dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="-5dp">
    </ImageView>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Got a problem with your capslock key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch(v.getId()){

case R.id.costumButton:
    adapter.updateView(1);
break;
.....
}

public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
     private int visibleFlag = 0;
     ///
     ////
    public void updateView(int flag) {
        visibleFlag = flag;
        notifydatasetchanged();
    }
   @Override
   public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {

       View MyView = convertView;
       final int pos=position;

       LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)MyContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.favor_item, null);


       ImageView iv = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.favor_item_image);
       iv.setImageResource(favorSites.get(pos));

       deleteFavorImage = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.favDelete);
       if (visibleFlag == 1)
            deleteFavorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       deleteFavorImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dubtndelete);

       return MyView;
   }
```

Comment: You should check in getView if convertView is null and only then inflate the view. Reuse convertView if it is already not null, because then it is an instance of a gridview item that just went out of the visible space and wants to be reused.

This saves memory and performance since you don't have wasted gridview item instances that have to be garbage collected during scrolling of the gridview.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution as I was same problem.

Define globally on class `int positionSelected = 0;`

And in gridview click listner

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            positionSelected=position;
            ((BaseAdapter)gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }
    });
```

And in getview method put below code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_color_images_row,
                    null);
        img_uparrow = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.img_uparrow);
        if(positionSelected==position){
                 img_uparrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
         else
             img_uparrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

return vi;
    }
```